# SenseTalk, the coding language used in Eggplant, does not have a tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-creation-process

Currently, there exists the [eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eggplant) tag, which covers all questions related to Eggplant, which is an image-based automated testing tool. Eggplant has its own coding language, named [SenseTalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SenseTalk).

Right now on Stack Overflow, the [eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eggplant) tag contains both questions about the software itself and questions regarding SenseTalk syntax and style.

I see three possible solutions to SenseTalk's tagless nature:

1. Leave [eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eggplant) as-is, but create a new tag [sensetalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sensetalk) that can be a synonym of [eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eggplant).
2. Create the [sensetalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sensetalk) tag, directing questions about the language itself to the new tag. (Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581448/eggplant-how-to-update-a-csv-file-in-senstalk), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567378/how-can-i-uncomment-a-xml-tag-in-eggplant), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419176/how-to-escape-escape-characters-in-eggplant-sensetalk-language).)
3. Carry out option (2), but only when the [eggplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eggplant) tag is populated with enough questions that a split is necessary. Until then, carry out option (1).

I'm rather new to Stack Overflow and don't know what the correct course of action should be.

Comment: Are there any existing questions where the new tag would make sense?

Comment: @JoeW Most of them, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581448/eggplant-how-to-update-a-csv-file-in-senstalk), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567378/how-can-i-uncomment-a-xml-tag-in-eggplant), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419176/how-to-escape-escape-characters-in-eggplant-sensetalk-language). If you browse the Eggplant questions, it becomes quickly evident that the majority of the questions regard SenseTalk, not Eggplant Functional itself.

Comment: If you want to request a new tag you should include questions where the tag would be used and why it would be a good tag to add to them. As for others browsing the tag not everyone knows enough about the product to be able to clearly see that the tag is needed

Comment: @JoeW Thanks for that information. First, though, I want to hear yours and others' opinions about if that's the correct approach.

Comment: And providing questions where the tag would be appropriately used helps people make a better opinion about it.

Comment: @JoeW thanks for the feedback. I've included the examples in my question.